# As an imam leading the fajr/maghrib/isha prayer, is it wajib or sunnah to recite out loud (vs silently)?

Tags: salat, fiqh

It is more than standard for the imam to recite out loud during the first two rakat of fajr, maghrib and isha prayer.

However what is the actual ruling of this practice - wajib or mustahab? In other words, if the imam recites silently then did he actually commit a sin/mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obligatory according to the Hanafis and sunnah according to the Malikis, Shafi'is and Hanbalis. Making a mistake in it requires a prostration of error or forgetfulness according to the Hanafis, and Malikis.

**Ref:** https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/16561/

Comment: So in the maliki, shafi and hanbali schools the imam has committed no fault whatsoever and no sin if he recited silently in the first two rakat of these prayers?